# Recursively list files in provided directory in the style of `npm ls`

Tags: javascript, recursion, node.js, file-system, formatting

I've written a small CLI node program to list the contents of a directory with an output similar to that provided by [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) but listing both files and directories, not just directories. I wrote this for two reasons:

1. Personal interest: practice recursion
2. Frequently I want see the contents of a directory without having to go to Finder and expand every folder.

Presently, generating a list composed of ~380 files takes 430ms.

**Sample output:**

```
  /Users/thomas/somedir/testDirectory
 └──┬   levelTwoDirectory1
 |  ├───   emptyDirectory
 |  └───   text1-1.txt
 └──┬   levelTwoDirectory2
 |  └──┬   levelThreeDirectory1
 |  |  └──┬   levelFourDirectory1
 |  |  |  ├───   image4-1-1.jpg
 |  |  |  └───   text4-2-2.txt
 |  |  ├───   image3-2-1.jpg
 |  |  └───   text3-2-1.txt
 |  └───   text2-1.txt
 ├───   text0-1.txt
 └───   text0-2.txt
```

**index.js**

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

'use strict'

const yargs = require('yargs').argv
    , path = require('path')
    , fs = require('fs')
    , isImage = require('is-image')
    , junk = require('junk')
    , _sortBy = require('lodash.sortby')
    , chalk = require('chalk');

function listFiles(source, parentDistance, firstRun, callback) {
    parentDistance = parentDistance || 0;
    firstRun = firstRun || false;
    source = path.resolve(path.sep + source);

    if(firstRun){
        console.log(' ', chalk.bgWhite.blue(source));
    }

    let items = fs.readdirSync(source).filter(junk.not);

    //items = filterGitIgnore(items);

    //single item and path to object containing type, icon, etc
    let itemsAsObj = items.map((item, index, itemsArr) => { 
        return getFileProperties(source, item, index, itemsArr);
    });

    //sort to put directories first by name, then all other file types alphabetically

    itemsAsObj = _sortBy(itemsAsObj, [function(o) { return o.type !== 'dir'; }, 'name']);
    let index = 0;
    for(let item of itemsAsObj){

        let pathAndItemLen = item.fullPath.split(path.sep).filter(Boolean).length;
        let distanceFromBase = pathAndItemLen - baseDirLen;

        //continue loop if `maxDepth` has been specified
        if(maxDepth && distanceFromBase > maxDepth){
            continue;
        }

        if(item.type === 'dir'){
            //print item and recurse function
            console.log(' | '.repeat(distanceFromBase-1), item.familyStatus.bracket, item.icon, item.item);
            listFiles(item.fullPath, distanceFromBase);
        }else{
            //print item
            console.log(' | '.repeat(distanceFromBase-1), item.familyStatus.bracket, item.icon, item.item);
        }
        index++;        
    }
}

function getFileProperties(source, item, index, items, maxDepth, distanceFromBase){

  let fullPath = path.join(source, item);
    let isImageFlag = isImage(fullPath);
    let isDirFlag = isDirectory(fullPath);
    let familyStatus = getFamilyStatus(fullPath, item, items, index);
    let returnObj = {};

  returnObj.item = item;
  returnObj.fullPath = fullPath;
  returnObj.familyStatus = familyStatus;

  if(isImageFlag){
    returnObj.type = 'image';
    returnObj.icon = ' ';
  }else if(isDirFlag){
    returnObj.type = 'dir';
    returnObj.icon = ' ';
  }else{
    returnObj.type = 'file';
    returnObj.icon = ' ';
  }
  return returnObj;
}

function isDirectory(item){
    return fs.lstatSync(item).isDirectory();
}

function getFamilyStatus(fullPath, item, items, index){

    let ret = {};
    if(hasChildren(fullPath, item, items, index)){
        ret.succession = 'patriarch';
        ret.bracket = '└──┬';   
    }else if(isFirstChild(index)){
        ret.succession = 'first child';
        ret.bracket = '├───';
    }else if(isMiddleChild(items, index)){
        ret.succession = 'middle child';
        ret.bracket = '├───';
    }else if(isLastChild(items, index)){
        ret.succession = 'last child';
        ret.bracket = '└───';
    }
    return ret;
}

function hasChildren(fullPath, item, items, index){
    if(isDirectory(fullPath) && fs.readdirSync(fullPath).length > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function isFirstChild(index){
    return index === 0;
}

function isMiddleChild(items, index){
  return index !== 0 && index !== items.length-1;
}

function isLastChild(items, index){
    return index === items.length-1;
}

let baseDir = process.cwd();
let baseDirLen = baseDir.split(path.sep).filter(Boolean).length;

let maxDepth = yargs.maxdepth || yargs.depth || false;
listFiles(baseDir, 0, true);

module.exports = listFiles;
```